# Cannot upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade

First on terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

and in the responce:

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable'
```

I try:

```
apt list --upgradable
```

and

```
dh-python/groovy,groovy 4.20200925 all [upgradable from: 4.20191017ubuntu7]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

the -a switch gives the same message.

Upgrade from GUI does nothing and from terminal:

```
update-manager
```

the responce is:

```
Checking for a newer version of Ubuntu
Please install all necessary updates for your version before attempting an upgrade.
```

Comment: Correctly it should be `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Confirm at the end to let it install all updates.

Comment: From the messages you get, I would try to run "sudo apt upgrade", and then perform the dis upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `python-is-python2` links python to python2 and python2 is deprecated. The current version of `dh-python` breaks `python` which is provided by `python-is-python2`.

In any case, `python-is-python2` should only be installed if it is needed to run old python based, third-party software. Otherwise, they recommend removing `python-is-python2`.

The first thing I would do is remove `python-is-python2` but be careful and review the list of packages to be removed before you accept the changes to ensure you don't inadvertently uninstall something you want to keep.

```
sudo apt uninstall python-is-python2
```

Then, upgrade `dh-python`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall dh-python
```

Additionally, you may want to install `python-is-python3` to replace the old python2 package and symlink `/usr/bin/python` to python3.

Run the following commands for more information:

```
apt-cache show python-is-python2
apt-cache show dh-python
```

Also, I found [this bug](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/GNKz-dSdygg?pli=1).

Comment: Thank you, your response was very helpful ! I followed your suggestions and I  managed to upgrade the system.